# Is there a way to apply a formula to each cell in a row than sum that row?

Tags: excel, vba, rows

I am currently trying to create a VBA program that calculates the final mark for students based on a formula and sum.

The formula I am using is: (studentsmark * percent)/max

This formula needs to be applied to each cell for each student. So for example the student Andy, I would apply this formula from A1(assignemnt 1) all the way to Final exam and then add each of the equations up and ouput the result into the Final Mark cell.

So this what I have started with but when I run it, all of the cells under FinalMark say #NAME?

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub grades()
    
    Dim row as Integer
    
       For row = 9 To 34

       Cells(row,18).Value = "Sum(row)"

       Next row

    End Sub
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this error/sum the cells in each row and output it into the FinalMark cell?

Apperciate any help or suggestions!
[image: Excel sheet of students marks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by simple `Sum()` formula like `R9` cell formula will be `=Sum(B9:Q9)` then drag and down till last row. If your choice is `VBA` then try below sub.

```
Sub grades()
Dim row As Integer

   For row = 9 To 34
    Cells(row, 18).Formula = "=Sum(B" & row & ":Q" & row & ")"
   Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome that worked! So then if I wanted to use my formula (studentsmark * percent)/max) how would I apply it to each of the cells for each row?

Comment: @Josh3.14 Then please mark it as answered (tick it).